# How to import csv file got by curl request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, curl

I need to get a csv file from curl request and then save it, what is the way to do that, I am using Ruby on Rails
here is what is in my controller:

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
require 'csv'
csv_text = File.read('...')
csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers => true)
csv.each do |row|
 Moulding.create!(row.to_hash)
end
end
```

curl request: curl -F „file=@/home/elsyser/file.csv“ http://yourherokuapp/sums

Answer (score 1):

You could run system commands using system()

for example

```
command = 'curl www.google.com'
system(command)
```

If you can go outside of curl, have a look at OpenURI. https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html

References:

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-system
https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html

Hope this helps out.